# How can I show array in erb template?

Tags: ruby, erb

I have this hash, it's a result of query to my management system.

```
a = {
  "total" => 3310,
  "subtotal" => 2,
  "page" => 1,
  "per_page" => 20,
  "search" => "fact = ipaddress and host ~ test.com",
  "sort" => { "by" => nil, "order" => nil },
  "results" => {
    "host1.test.com" => { "ipaddress" => "192.168.253.240" },
    "host2.test.com" => { "ipaddress" => "192.168.253.253" }
  }
}
```

And I want to store this pool of IP adresses of my hosts in new array and show the new arrays's values with template erb file. 
Somethig like this:

```
host1.test.com 192.168.253.240
host2.test.com 192.168.253.253
```

The result of the request can be a different number of hosts with different name. This hash is an example.

Comment: `puts a["results"].map {|k,v| [k,v["ipaddress"]].join(' ') }`

Comment: sagarpandya82, thanks! This is useful variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign it to a variable - `@ip_addresses`

```
@ip_addresses = a['results']
```

Then use it in the template file

```
<% @ip_addresses.each do |host, info| %>
  <%= host %> - <%= info['ipaddress'] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```